# How do I apply QScintilla syntax highlighting to a QTextEdit in PyQt4?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, scintilla, qscintilla

I have a simple PyQt text editor, and would like to apply QScintilla formatting to it. I need to use a QTextEdit for the text, as it provides other functionality that I am using (cursor position, raw text output, etc), and would like to apply QScintilla formatting.

Just for refrence, the initialisation of the QTextEdit:

```
self.text = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
```

Comment: You can't - they just do not work in the same way at all. For `QTextEdit`, use [QSyntaxHighlighter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsyntaxhighlighter.html).

Comment: Please check out this new website with a beginners tutorial on QScintilla: http://qscintilla.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you cannot use `QScintilla` directly with `QTextEdit`.

But have a look at this question: stackoverflow.com/questions/20951660/… and if you want to see the usage `QTextEdit` (or `QPlainTextEdit`) with `QSyntaxHiglighter`, see for example this: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Python%20syntax%20highlighting or this http://carsonfarmer.com/2009/07/syntax-highlighting-with-pyqt/ which uses very basic syntax highlighter for Python code.